# Python code to break .xlsx file having 52000 rows into 11 excel files (10 xlsx files with 5000 rows and 1 file with remaining 2000 records)

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I am trying to write a Python code to break .xlsx file having 52000 rows into 11 excel files (10 xlsx files with 5000 rows and 1 file with remaining 2000 records)

having a hard time finding a good online solution

Tried the below solution which is producing exact desired outcome but it is also producing blank 49,996 xlsx files

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\rajat.kapoor\\Desktop\\All Data Combined\\Credit Check Data.xlsx")
n_partitions = 5000

for i in range(n_partitions):
    sub_df = df.iloc[(i*n_partitions): ((i+1)*n_partitions)]
    sub_df.to_excel(f"C:\\Users\\rajat.kapoor\\Desktop\\All Data Combined\\Credit Check Data - {i}.xlsx", sheet_name="a")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the increment step from 1 to 5000. So you would only create 11 excel files. Since rest similar I am showing the different part below.

```
for i in range(0,52000,5000):

   sub_df = df.iloc[(i): ((i+5000))]
```